# Error in nlme.formula: step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step

Tags: r, lme4, nlme, mle, random-effects

#### Data

I have a longitudinal dataset for plant growth that includes repeated measurements in different seasons. It is a large dataset with over 100 individuals,so I can't put all the data here but the data look like this

```
> df
head(dat)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  id      season  Lt_1    td  Lobs
  <fct>   <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-15 s1      35      60  40.2
2 2020-15 s1      40.2    94  41.7
3 2020-20 s1      37.3    60  41.7
4 2020-21 s1      35.5    59  39.4
5 2020-24 s1      36.6    60  41.8
6 2020-24 s1      41.8    80  45.1
```

#### Model to estimate parameters

I am trying to estimate the parameters for a growth equation using this dataset. The growth equation is as follows:

> Lobs = 150*((1 + ((150/Lt_1)^(1/p)-1)exp(-k*td/365))^(-p))

Lt represents the plant height at a measurement, Lt_1 represents the plant height at the previous measurement, and td represents the duration of time between measurements. The parameters I want to estimate are k and p. However, I believe that the parameter k may vary depending on the season, so I want to have specific k values for each season. Additionally, I would like to include individual variation as a random effect in the model.

#### Issue

Now, I am trying to estimate the parameters using the `nlme` function from the `nlme` package. However, I am getting the error below.

```
library(nlme)
# Model formula
formula = Lobs ~ 150*((1 + ((150/Lt_1)^(1/p)-1)*exp(-k*td/365))^(-p))

# specify starting values for the parameters
p = 1.2
k = c(0.5, 1.09, 0.75, 1.09)

# fitting
model <- nlme(formula,
              fixed = c(p ~ 1, k ~ 1 + season),
              random = k ~ 1 | id,
              data = df_r,
              start = list(fixed = c(p, k)),
              control=list(maxIter=1e6, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE)
)
  0:     1150.3155:  2.85771
  1:     1150.3141:  2.86659
  2:     1150.3141:  2.86654
  0:     1103.1191:  4.57637
  1:     1103.1180:  4.65814
  2:     1103.1172:  4.62838
  3:     1103.1172:  4.62391
  4:     1103.1172:  4.62430
  5:     1103.1172:  4.62430
Error in nlme.formula(formula, fixed = c(p ~ 1, k ~ 1 + season), random = k ~  : 
  step halving factor reduced below minimum in PNLS step
```

#### What I tried

I tried with different starting values and the number of iterations, but none of them worked out.
Only when I remove the `season` variable from the fixed effect, it succeeded to fit.

```
p = 1.2
k = 0.2
model <- nlme(formula,
              fixed = c(p ~ 1, k ~ 1),
              random = k ~ 1 | id,
              data = dat,
              start = list(fixed = c(p, k)),
              control=list(maxIter=1e6, msMaxIter = 1e6, msVerbose = TRUE)
)
> summary(model)
Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: formula 
  Data: dat 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1631.918 1646.773 -811.9589

Random effects:
 Formula: k ~ 1 | id
                 k Residual
StdDev: 0.02607074 3.500357

Fixed effects:  c(p ~ 1, k ~ 1) 
     Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
p 4.154633  3.263363 181  1.273114  0.2046
k 0.666089  0.055864 181 11.923354  0.0000
 Correlation: 
  p     
k -0.976

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-3.6905297 -0.8627678 -0.2492133  0.4294071  2.4403191 

Number of Observations: 303
Number of Groups: 121
```

**Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?**